# How to print table columns to use in an INSERT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run some SQL which will return my columns from a table.

I need to use these columns in an INSERT statement.

I could run:

```
select * 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'tableName'
```

but I need to print something like this:

```
[table.custid], [table.address], [table.name]
```

Comment: Why would you want to produce something that is  not a valid reference to columns in the table?  (`[table].[custid]` would be a valid column reference; `[table.custid]` would be a very unlikely column reference.)

Comment: I think you added wrong tag there .`information_schema` is available in `MYSQL` and not in `SQLServer`

Comment: `information_schema` is allowed in SQL-Server.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), my guess is that you are about to use dynamic SQL to generate an insert table, which just seems fraught with problems.

Comment: I would normally point out anyway my preference of the [system catalog views over the information_schema views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views), but it is especially relevant if you are generating a list of columns for an insert because the information_schema does not allow you to identify computed columns, or identity columns, whereas `sys.columns` allows you to omit both of these with ease: `FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Tablename') AND Iscomputed = 0 AND IsIdentity = 0`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton, [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29538154/3208640) edited it now gives the tablename prefix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought you may need them to use for example with dynamic sql, you can get the list of column in the format you want as:

```
DECLARE @ColNames VARCHAR(1000) 
SELECT @ColNames = COALESCE(@ColNames+', ', '') + QUOTENAME('tableName.'+NAME,'[')
FROM SYS.COLUMNS
WHERE OBJECT_id = OBJECT_id('tableName')
SELECT @ColNames
```

**Edit summary:** adding tablename prefix to columns as wanted in question

Comment: @JohnLBevan thanks for the edit, I also changed the `name` to `Column_name`

Comment: yes I did, it was better, thanks and apologize for editing your edit.

Comment: No worries.  ps. you may also want to change `information_schema.column` to `sys.columns`; that's the underlying table by the info schema view (see `EXEC sp_helptext [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS]`) so would be slightly faster - though performance isn't the biggest worry here.

Comment: exactly, I just gone through the OP's query, please edit the answer and add it.

Comment: no worries; I was adding a comment to explain my edit, forgetting that you'd spot it in the edit itself; deleted once I saw you'd spotted :).  sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName') 

DECLARE @sql as VARCHAR(8000)
SET @sql = ' '

SELECT @sql += '[table.'+[Name] + '],' FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName') 

PRINT(@sql)
```